# Zend insert prevent specific escaping

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

So due to a design decision that pervades our application, I need to be able to insert carriage returns into the database. I store the information in a string, and then use Zend's insert, but that escapes the escape character, so the string:

```
This is an entry\rsplit across two lines
```

Is actually inserted into the database exactly as written, with the literal `\r` in the string. I need it to be inserted without escaping the \ so the actual carriage return is put in the database.

The Zend Form has a text box and a multiselect box. The user can enter text into the text box, press a button, and then it gets added to the multiselect box. My code:

```
$info['choices'] = '';
foreach ($info['choice_list'] as $choice) {
    $info['choices'] .= $choice . '\r';
}
$info['choices'] = substr_replace($info['choices'], "", -2);
```

$info is just an array of table fields => values that I pass to Zend's `->update` I use the substr_replace at the end to just trim off the last `\r`

Comment: Could you show us some code? ZF won't change the data that's inserted into the DB.

Comment: Added the code that generates the string

Comment: And posting the code (or sleeping on it) made me realize my mistake. I needed double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Also, the code you posted could be simplified to one line: `$info['choices'] = implode("\r", $info['choice_list']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved, the issue was using single quotes instead of double quotes. Changing my code to:

```
$info['choices'] = "";
foreach ($info['choice_list'] as $choice) {
    $info['choices'] .= $choice . "\r";
}
$info['choices'] = substr_replace($info['choices'], "", -2);
```

Fixed the issue.